# SwiftyJSON not working with WebSocket message

Tags: json, swift, websocket, swifty-json

I have a socket response that is this:

```
{"op":0,"d":{"author":{"id":"6699457769390473216","name":"Test","verified":false},"unixTime":1597277057132,"id":"6699465549836976128","group":"64632423765273287342","content":"Yo","_id":"5f34838198980c0023fa49e3"},"t":"MESSAGE"}
```

and I need to access the "d" object, I've tried doing

```swift
print(JSON(data)["d"])
```

and it just Returns `null` every time.

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

If `data` is of type String, you are probably using the wrong init method to initialize the `JSON` object. Try using `init(parseJSON:)` like this:

```
let jsonString = """
{
    "op": 0,
    "d": {
        "author": {
            "id": "6699457769390473216",
            "name": "Test",
            "verified": false
        },
        "unixTime": 1597277057132,
        "id": "6699465549836976128",
        "group": "64632423765273287342",
        "content": "Yo",
        "_id": "5f34838198980c0023fa49e3"
    },
    "t": "MESSAGE"
}
"""
let json = JSON(parseJSON: jsonString)

print(json["d"])
```